# Exporting Metatrader 4 historical data to excel

Tags: export-to-excel, mql4, metatrader4

I got the following code which run as script and I have a problem with blank rows in between like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LB2N.png)

I've been trying to figure out and not sure why there are blank rows. Any help would be appreciated .Here is the code:

```
#property script_show_inputs  

input datetime StartDateTime = D'2023.11.21 00:00';  
input datetime EndDateTime   = D'2023.11.22 12:00';  

// ------ OnInit() function ------
int OnInit() 
{
   string filename = "MyMT4Data.csv";
   int file_handle = FileOpen(filename, FILE_WRITE | FILE_CSV | FILE_ANSI);

   if (file_handle == INVALID_HANDLE) {
       Print("Failed to open file: ", filename);
       return(INIT_FAILED);
   }

   // Loop through bars in reverse order, and filter by StartDateTime and EndDateTime
   for (int i = Bars - 1; i >= 0; i--) {  
       datetime barTime = Time[i];

       if (barTime >= StartDateTime && barTime <= EndDateTime) {
           // Build CSV line 

           // Explicit Line Initialization (Safeguard)
           string line =""; 

           line = TimeToString(barTime, TIME_DATE | TIME_SECONDS) + "," + 
                  DoubleToString(Open[i], Digits) + "," + 
                  DoubleToString(High[i], Digits) + "," + 
                  DoubleToString(Low[i], Digits) + "," + 
                  DoubleToString(Close[i], Digits) + "\n"; 

           // Modify line to get four-digit year
           line = StringSubstr(line, 0, 8) + StringSubstr(line, 11); 

           // Remove any leading spaces (if needed)
           line = StringTrimLeft(line); 

           // Write to file
           FileWrite(file_handle, line); 
           line ="";                  
       }
   }

   FileClose(file_handle); 
   return(INIT_SUCCEEDED); 
}
```

I have tried to print to debug so many times and still blank rows happen

Answer (score 0):

I assume, since you're declaring each line individually and add it to your CSV, those lines don't need the `\n (new line)` character after the addition of `Close`.

Delete that `\n` and I think you'll be fine.